# s there a way to get the height of the drone from the infrared sensor on Windows SDK?

Tags: windows, dji-sdk

I am using *Windows SDK* and Mavic 2 Pro. I would like to get the *altitude* of the drone from the **infrared sensor**, located on the bottom of it. I have seen that this is possible on *Android SDK* through the method *getUltrasonicHeightInMeters()*. However, I cannot find a similar method on its Window counterpart.

**UPDATE**

I have been playing with the drone and taking information from several sensors, including the Baro. It looks that the height coming from the Baro is really accurate. I tested taking off, landing and changing height indoor and it was constant.

Answer (score 0):

In windows SDK it is called altitude

see https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/FlightControllerHandler.html?search=altitude&i=4&#flightcontrollerhandler_getaltitudeasync_inline

```
method GetAltitudeAsync
async Task<ResultValue<DoubleMsg?>> GetAltitudeAsync()
Declaration:    DJI.WindowsSDK.Components
Description:
Gets the flight controller's relative altitude of the aircraft relative to take off location, measured by the barometer, in meters.

Return:
async Task<ResultValue<DoubleMsg?>> A Task<ResultValue<DoubleMsg?>> object.
```

## Edit

IR port not open to outside SDK and there is no open plan for DJI to merge it with down streaming vision data.

One way to walk around for flat terrian is to use brao fuse with the GPS height using Extended kalman filter.

If you want to avoid the obstacle in complex terrain, you can always use some advanced method such as SVO https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo . It only uses video stream and output the Depth you needed. This work from ETH group is pretty trustworthy and can perform in the low to high altitude outdoor environment without any issue.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR8uq1RTUfA

You can use the normal camera stream like the DJI Wsdk output. The 3D points are mapped in a relative scale. By using with GPS or baro, you can get the close approximation to true scale.

[image]

Comment: Hi, actually that method uses the barometer to offer the altitude, which is inaccurate. I was hopping to get the altitude from the infrared sensor when I am close to the ground.

Comment: IR port is not open yet and it is functioning as internal detection model. Not sure DJI will have plan in merging the normal video stream with downward looking IR.  For now, you can use baro with GPS height for flat terrian. For complex terrian, doesn`t looks like you have much choice on drone sensor it self.  One way to walk around is to use SVO https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR8uq1RTUfA for remote sensing the spase depth and record in the memory,  and control the drone.